# link_to action "show" to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, link-to

- ruby 1.9.2p290
- rails 3.1.1

Basically I have two models: CHEFS and RECIPES.

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base 
 has_many :recipes
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :chef
end
```

And the following routes:

```
resources :recipes

resources :chefs do
 # list of recipes from chef
 resources :recipes, :to => 'recipes#index_chef'
end
```

With this I have the urls (exactly what I want):

- /recipes *- list of recipes*
- /chefs/username/recipes *- list of chef's recipes*
- /chefs/ *- list of chefs*
- /chefs/username *- chef's profile*

**RecipesController:**

```
def index
 @chef = Chef.find_by_username(params[:chef_id])
 @recipes = Recipe.where({ :status_id => 1 }).order("id desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)
end

def index_chef
  @chef = Chef.find_by_username(params[:chef_id])
  @recipes = @chef.recipes.where(:status_id => 1).order("id desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)
end
```

My recipes **index** view:

```
<%= link_to recipe.chef.username.capitalize, @chef %>
```

In http://3001/chefs/username/recipes I have the correct link to Chef profile.

But in http://3001/recipes I have the wrong link.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't specify what the intended outcome is or what the current result is.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain correctly (my english is not so good).
I want the link_to to Chef's show action (/chefs/username) in index view of Recipe's controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In http://3001/recipes (which is a weird url!), you don't have access to `params[:chef_id]`. So you won't have the @chef variable available to you in the view. It should be `nil`!

To get around this, change your link_to to this

```
<%= link_to recipe.chef.username.capitalize, recipe.chef %>
```

You might want to eager load the chef to your `@recipes` records by loading that in your controller like this:

```
 @recipes = Recipe.where({ :status_id => 1 }).includes(:chef).order("id desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Phyo, thank you very much! Works nicely. The eager loading hint too. I'm new on rails! 

Why did you think that url is weird?

Comment: Usually it's like http://127.0.0.1:3001/recipes or http://localhost:3001/recipes etc. Maybe you have changed your host file ?

Comment: Sure, you are right. For some reason I omitted the **localhost:**